# How to differentiate as abbreviation for voice response in dialog flow

Tags: chatbot, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have integrated my dialogflow agent with google assistant. There is a welcome intent that will ask you to choose any of the option

`Choose any of the sports
1. NBA
2. NHL
3. FIH`

It reads the response with ever individual words(as an abbreviation). But when I produce the same in  response from webhook, it is not reading the response with individual words(or not considering the response as abbreviation) and reads together. How can I achieve this? Am I missing something in the response?

Answer (score 3):

You likely want to make sure you're sending back [SSML](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml) in your response, rather than sending back text and letting it convert it to speech, and specifically marking the abbreviations using the `<say-as>` tag and telling it to interpret the contents as characters.

So you might send it back as something like:

```
<speak>
  Are you interested in learning more about 
  the <say-as interpret-as="characters">NBA</say-as>,
  the <say-as interpret-as="characters">NHL</say-as>
  or the <say-as interpret-as="characters">FIH</say-as>?
</speak>
```

Answer (score 0):

The little pronunciation differences with and without SSML are serious problems. I stick in a speak /speak for everything. Also a unique number I like and a test hook to have speech 'count' or not so there is a way to test things. Also a hook so an intent is triggered for 'repeat that please' :

Point is to use sayUsual for everything ordinary.

```
// Mostly SSML start char kit as globals
  const startSp = "<speak>", endSp = "</speak>";

// Handle "Can you repeat that ?" well
  var vfSpokenByMe = "";

// VF near globals what was said, etc
  var repeatPossible = {}; repeatPossible.vf = ""; repeatPossible.n = 0;

// An answer from this app to the human in text
  function absorbMachineVf( intentNumber, aKind, aStatement )
  {
    // Numbers reserved for 'repeats'
    if( intentNumber > 9000 ) { return; }

    // Machine to say this, a number for intents too
    repeatPossible.vf = aStatement; repeatPossible.n = intentNumber;
  }


// Usual way to say a thing
  function sayUsual( n, speechAgent, somethingToSay )
  {
    // Work with an answer of any sort
    absorbMachineVf( n, 'usual', somethingToSay );

    // Sometimes we are just pretending, so
    if( !testingNow )
    { speechAgent.add( startSp + somethingToSay + endSp ); }

    // Make what we said as an answer available 'for sure' to rest of code
    vfSpokenByMe = somethingToSay;                            // Even in simulation
  }
```